# Magento 2 : install error

Tags: magento2, error, installation, wamp

i want to install on windows with wamp server, but it always take error when 36%  like this:

```
Starting Maijindou installation:
File permissions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_Quote':

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_User':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_Sales':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_Integration':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_Paypal':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_Reports':

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_Weee':

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':

Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running recurring.. 
[ERROR] Exception: Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter.php on line 79 in E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'array_merge(): ...', 'E:\\wamp64\\www\\m...', 79, Array) #1 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter.php(79): array_merge('Copyright \xC2\xA9 20...', Array) #2 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter->_convertNode(Object(DOMElement), 'design/footer/c...') #3 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter->_convertNode(Object(DOMElement), 'design/footer') #4 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter->_convertNode(Object(DOMElement), 'design') #5 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter.php(46): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter->_convertNode(Object(DOMElement)) #6 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter->convert(Object(DOMDocument)) #7 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #8 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter\Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter\Interceptor->___callPlugins('convert', Array, Array) #9 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Reader.php(115): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Converter\Interceptor->convert(Object(DOMDocument)) #10 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Reader\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Reader->read() #11 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial.php(43): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Reader\Proxy->read() #12 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(99): Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Reader\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\Config)) #13 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #14 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #15 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...') #16 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'initialConfig', 'Magento\\Store\\M...') #17 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Store\\M...', Array, Array) #18 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Store\\M...') #19 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(273): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Store\\M...') #20 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(249): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray(Array) #21 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(53): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, NULL, NULL, 'readers', 'Magento\\Store\\M...') #22 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(82): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Store\\M...', Array, Array) #23 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Store\\M...') #24 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\var\generation\Magento\Store\Model\Config\Reader\ReaderPool\Proxy.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Store\\M...') #25 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\var\generation\Magento\Store\Model\Config\Reader\ReaderPool\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Store\Model\Config\Reader\ReaderPool\Proxy->_getSubject() #26 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopePool.php(82): Magento\Store\Model\Config\Reader\ReaderPool\Proxy->getReader('store') #27 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config.php(45): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopePool->getScope('store', 'default') #28 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Config.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('catalog/fronten...', 'store', NULL) #29 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\app\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\AbstractFlatState.php(57): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('catalog/fronten...', 'store') #30 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\app\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\Plugin\IndexerConfigData.php(43): Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\AbstractFlatState->isFlatEnabled() #31 [internal function]: Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\Plugin\IndexerConfigData->aroundGet(Object(Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Interceptor), Object(Closure), NULL, NULL) #32 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #33 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Indexer...', 'get', Object(Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Interceptor), Array, 'indexerCategory...') #34 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\app\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\Plugin\IndexerConfigData.php(40): Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(NULL, NULL) #35 [internal function]: Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\Plugin\IndexerConfigData->aroundGet(Object(Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Interceptor), Object(Closure), NULL, NULL) #36 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #37 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\var\generation\Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Interceptor->___callPlugins('get', Array, Array) #38 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\var\generation\Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy.php(103): Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Interceptor->get(NULL, NULL) #39 [internal function]: Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy->get(NULL, NULL) #40 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(74): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #41 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(70): Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy\Interceptor->___callParent('get', Array) #42 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Indexer...', 'get', Object(Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy\Interceptor), Array, 'indexerProductF...') #43 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\app\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\Plugin\IndexerConfigData.php(41): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(NULL, NULL) #44 [internal function]: Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Product\Flat\Plugin\IndexerConfigData->aroundGet(Object(Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy\Interceptor), Object(Closure), NULL, NULL) #45 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain.php(67): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #46 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(136): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Indexer...', 'get', Object(Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy\Interceptor), Array, 'indexerCategory...') #47 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\app\code\Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\Plugin\IndexerConfigData.php(40): Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(NULL, NULL) #48 [internal function]: Magento\Catalog\Model\Indexer\Category\Flat\Plugin\IndexerConfigData->aroundGet(Object(Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy\Interceptor), Object(Closure)) #49 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(140): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #50 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\var\generation\Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy\Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy\Interceptor->___callPlugins('get', Array, Array) #51 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\app\code\Magento\Indexer\Model\Config.php(32): Magento\Indexer\Model\Config\Data\Proxy\Interceptor->get() #52 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\app\code\Magento\Indexer\Setup\Recurring.php(90): Magento\Indexer\Model\Config->getIndexers() #53 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(821): Magento\Indexer\Setup\Recurring->install(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), Object(Magento\Setup\Model\ModuleContext)) #54 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(732): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData(Object(Magento\Setup\Module\Setup), 'schema') #55 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema() #56 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(331): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #57 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(97): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #58 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(82): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #59 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #60 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #61 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #62 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #63 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #64 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #65 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(444): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #66 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(205): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #67 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #68 E:\wamp64\www\magento\Maijindou\setup\index.php(31): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #69 {main}
```

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried installing previously? if so drop the database as its trying to perform actions which have already been started

Answer (score 0):

you can install using command line

command is

`php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/mag232/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="mag232" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@admin.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="INR" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"`

you need to change this command as per your store details

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the PHP version used in your stack and the way it behaves.
I have seen this behavior mostly when upgrading any project from a php5 version to php 7.1.x.

Your problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705733/warning-array-merge-argument-1-is-not-an-array-when-processing-two-post)

You should trace the php code(most likely the files on errors) that works that way and make the adjustments for the function to work as expected , otherwise change your php version to the one recommended for your Magento Version.

Edit: Looking at the php changelog i found this, so i believe this is your case as well:

```
Changelog:  As of PHP 5.0, this function only accept parameters of type array
```